# Django Query doesn't match

Tags: python, ajax, django, web

I have the following Django Model:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=False)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=False)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

In my views.py file I've created the following method:

```
def getCoords(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                state = request.POST['state'] #receives the state from JS
                stateInstance = State.objects.get(name=state)
                stateLat = stateInstance.latitude
                stateLong = stateInstance.longitude
                data = {"lat" : stateLat, "long" : stateLong}
             except State.DoesNotExist:
                 return HttpResponse("No record")

             return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data)) #returns json
```

So I'm sending this method a param through ajax, let's say "California". The state variable gets the value (I have proved that) but the query doesn't get executed, it returns the query doesn't match message. I've tried with the following as well:

```
    state = request.POST['state']
        if state == 'California':
            return HttpResponse("Yes!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse(state)
```

When this snippet returns the state it displays California which means state's value is correct but the query is not executed properly. I don't know what's going on. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you have such object in your database? Are your database settings properly configured?

Comment: Yes. I'm using mysql, admin is running properly and I have California in my state records.

Comment: You can use django-debug-toolbar (command `manage.py debugsqlshell`) to see what query was executed and what is the result set.

Comment: python manage.py debugsqlshell it says debugsqlshell is an unknown command. I'm on Linux, Django version is 1.4.5

Comment: what does it return exactly, what is the error message?

Comment: The error message says: matching query does not exist

Comment: Are you literally getting that exception, or are you getting the `HttpResponse("No Record")` you construct in your try/except block?

Comment: If I remove the try except it returns me the exception I posted above.

Comment: To use that command, you should first install django-debug-toolbar: `pip install django-debug-toolbar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're connecting to the correct database in your `settings.py`.  Make sure the record actually does exist with plain old SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM [app_name]_state WHERE name = 'California';
```

Also, try it from the Django shell. `python manage.py shell`

```
>>> from [app_name].models import State
>>> s = State.objects.get(name='California')
>>> s
<State: California>
```

Make sure that what is actually being sent is sent as POST, and not accidentally a GET variable in the URL.  Also, make sure that the post variable has no extra characters and that it is actually valid.  A decent way to do that is to just print it to the console, or if AJAX, with Firebug.

```
# Single quotes added so you can see any extra spaces in the console
print "'%s'" % state
```

Comment: Yeah, It works from Django shell I'm gonna try it in plain SQL. Thanks for the tip. EDIT: I just wrote the sql query and it worked. So the record exists. This is quite bizarre

Comment: If it works from the shell just fine, then it should work just fine in the Django Web output.  Your problem may be in what is being fed to the POST param `state`.  Make sure the parameter and value is spelled correctly in your POST request data(and not accidentally a GET variable in the URL).

Comment: when I send the param Firebug shows me this: Parameters: state California  Source: state=California%C2%A0  Do you think that source could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  You have an extra encoded non-breaking space there.  Trimming it before using it would help.  `State.objects.get(name=state.strip())`

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot Mike, you are a ninja. I'm coming from PHP and this never happened to me. You saved me. Thanks again mate.

Comment: No problem, I'll update my answer to include this possibility.